# Shortcomings of mysql_real_escape_string?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-injection, mysql-real-escape-string

I have seen a few people on here state that concatenating queries using `mysql_real_escape_string` will not protect you (entirely) from SQL injection attacks.

However, I am yet to see an example of input that illustrates an attack that `mysql_real_escape_string` would not protect you from. The majority of examples forget that `mysql_query` is limited to one query and use `mysql_real_escape_string` incorrectly.

The only example I can think of is the following:

```
mysql_query('DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id = '.mysql_real_escape_string($input));
```

This would not protect you from the following input:

```
5 OR 1=1
```

I would see this as incorrect usage of `mysql_real_escape_string` rather than a shortcoming, it is designed for strings not numeric values. You should either cast to a numeric type or if you are going to treat the input as a string when sanitising you should do the same in your query and wrap quotation marks around it.

Can anyone provide an example of input that can get around `mysql_real_escape_string` that does not rely on incorrect handling of numeric values or forget that `mysql_query` can only execute one query?

Edit: I am interested in the limitations of `mysql_real_escape_string` and not comparing it to alternatives, I realise there are better options for new projects and am not disputing that.

Comment: This question is deprecated. Why finding solutions for `mysql_*` when you have good alternatives?

Comment: This is a great question. I have seen the same FUD several times as well without any concrete backup that was not simply based on incorrect usage. Regardless of the fact that you should not be using mysql_ to begin with, I'd like to see an answer to this.

Comment: Mihai, I am not disputing there are better alternatives such as PDO, that is not the point of this question.

Comment: *"I have seen a few people on here state ..."* Have you tried asking those people? Good question though

Comment: I would guess they don't know a real example and I didn't want to pollute other questions with this discussion. Rather than asking one person in comments, I'd rather address the whole community with my own question.

Comment: This function doesn't escape the percent and the underscore (`%_`), which are wildcards in `LIKE`. Does that count as a shortcoming?

Comment: I guess that is a minor shortcoming but not the full-blown SQL injection attack I had in mind.

Comment: Pitty you ask this question now, a tad late since the deprecation process for `mysql_*` has begun, but I fully understand your wanting to know about possible malicious requests and how given functions fend them off

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main shortcoming of `mysql_real_escape_string`, or of the mysql_ extension in general, is that it is harder to apply correctly than other, more modern APIs, especially prepared statements. `mysql_real_escape_string` is supposed to be used in exactly one case: escaping text content that is used as a value in an SQL statement between quotes. E.g.:

```
$value = mysql_real_escape_string($value, $link);
$sql = "... `foo` = '$value' ...";
                     ^^^^^^
```

`mysql_real_escape_string` makes sure that the `$value` in the above context does not mess up the SQL syntax. It does not work as you may think here:

```
$sql = "... `foo` = $value ...";
```

or here:

```
$sql = "... `$value` ...";
```

or here:

```
$sql = mysql_real_escape_string("... `foo` = '$value' ...");
```

If applied to values which are used in any context other than a quoted string in an SQL statement, it is misapplied and may or may not mess up the resulting syntax and/or allow somebody to submit values which may enable SQL injection attacks. The use case of `mysql_real_escape_string` is very narrow, but is seldom correctly understood.

Another way to get yourself into hot water using `mysql_real_escape_string` is when you set the database connection encoding using the wrong method. You should do this:

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8', $link);
```

You *can* also do this though:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $link);
```

The problem is that the latter bypasses the mysql_ API, which still thinks you're talking to the database using `latin1` (or something else). When using `mysql_real_escape_string` now, it will assume the wrong character encoding and escape strings differently than the database will interpret them later. By running the `SET NAMES` query, you have created a rift between how the mysql_ client API is treating strings and how the database will interpret these strings. This can be used for injection attacks in certain multibyte string situations.

There are no fundamental injection vulnerabilities in `mysql_real_escape_string` that I am aware of **if it is applied correctly.** Again though, the main problem is that it is terrifyingly easy to apply it incorrectly, which opens up vulnerabilities.

Comment: Thank you deceze, it seems the claims on here of `mysql_real_escape_string` being open to injection only apply when it is used incorrectly. I am going to accept this as the answer.

Comment: See also [additional vulnerability when using `NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23277864/623041).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so apart from `mysql_*` being deprecated, I understand your wanting to *know* about any possible workaround that might exist. [perhaps this blog post](http://www.suspekt.org/2008/09/18/slides-from-my-lesser-known-security-problems-in-php-applications-talk-at-zendcon/) and the slides might reveal some of them.
But as [this older question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) here shows, casting and quoting isn't full proof. There's just *So many things that can wrong*, and Murphy's law, twined with that ever valid mantra *"Never trust the network"*, will go horribly wrong.

Perhaps [this article](http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/jan/addslashes-versus-mysql-real-escape-string), but most importantly, [the follow-up to that article](http://ilia.ws/archives/103-mysql_real_escape_string-versus-Prepared-Statements.html) can reveal even more security issues. To be honest, I know `mysql_real_escape_string` isn't fullproof, even in combination with type casting and string formats:

```
printf('WHERE id = \'%d\'',(int)mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['id']));
```

doesn't cover every possible attack. 
I'm no expert on this matter, but what I can tell you is sanitizing every input, will, if anything, give you a *FALSE* sense of security. Most of the time, you'll know (initially) what and why and how you protect against the attacks, but your colleagues might not. They might forget something, and your entire system is compromized.

In summary: Yes, you might be able to prevent *any form of malicious input* from getting to your DB, but every additional action it requires is an added risk. In that scenario, the greatest liability (as always) is the developer that hasn't had is fourth cup of coffee on a monday morning. No code, no matter how defensive and well thought out, can protect itself from the monster that is a tired developer with a bad temper, going cold turkey on caffeine and nicotine.

Comment: *How* exactly would you exploit the code snippet you show? The question (and I) asks for a specific, practical example.

Comment: The first two references you link to are classic attacks through incorrect application, the third even states *"To avoid this type of vulnerability, use `mysql_real_escape_string()` [...]"*. I'd consider this yet another non-answer.

Comment: @deceze: in itself, the snippet I posted can't be exploited, AFAIK, but can produce errors, and ppl with bad intentions like a good call stack when probing for vulnerabilities. It's also quite likely that you're going to be using more then 1 param in the `WHERE` clause, each of which requires three additional operations, (string format, type cast, and escape call), so this approach is error prone (get a cast or placeholder wrong and it's no longer safe). In the question I linked too, the point of collation is raised, too, which my snippet doesn't deal with at all

Comment: @deceze: as far as the third link goes, I was mainly focussing on the comment section to be honest, there somebody linked too [this follow-up](http://ilia.ws/archives/103-mysql_real_escape_string-versus-Prepared-Statements.html) which, I must admit, would have been more informative

Comment: The best these articles can point to is the well-known incorrect application of the GBK/charset problem. I.e. when you get yourself into a situation where `mysql_real_escape_string` assumes a different charset when doing its job than the database. This is easily avoided by using the mysql_ API to change the charset instead of bypassing it using a `SET NAMES` query. I'd agree that that's is a shortcoming of the API, but not really a vulnerability of `_real_escape_string`. The mysql_ API may be harder to apply correctly than PDO, but I have yet to see a *fundamental* vulnerability in it.

Comment: @deceze: I agree with you, I'm not going to say there is a fundamental vulnerability in the _extension_. That's why I summarized by saying the greatest liability lies in the developers, because there's a lot more things _they_ have to consider at any given moment.