# UTF8 text shows ???? when queried from db

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, sql, json

When i enter this code and call it from database it show the text as Question marks instead or letters, the are arabic letters , so UTF8 should work but i don't know whit won't now.

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

$server   = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$database = "";

$con = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password) or die ("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database, $con);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE id='1' ";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Query error: " . mysql_error());

$records = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $records[] = $row;
}

mysql_close($con);

print_r($records);

?>
```

it shows this as result

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [event] => ????? ?????
            [speaker] => ???? ???????
            [area] => ???????
            [place] => ???? ??????
            [addr] => ??? ???? ????????
            [datefrom] => 2012-10-05
            [dateto] => 
            [timefrom] => 19:26:27
            [timeto] => 
        )

)
```

Comment: Try adding this before your current query: `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");`.

Comment: Encoding issues. The encoding used to save data in DB differs from the one used by PHP to show data.

Comment: does your db supports UTF characters for storage

Comment: Also, consider modifying your code to use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead of the `mysql_*` functions, which are being deprecated.

Comment: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Answer (score 0):

Check that your database also uses UTF-8:

```
SHOW CREATE DATABASE `your_db_name`
```

How did you insert your data?

And also verify that your web server is well configured (to use UTF8).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set utf8 collation on the column where you store utf8:

```
rowname varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
```

...and also the connection is important (see answer from Roger Ng)

Answer (score -1):

Here is the code to set the connection between client and database to UTF-8

```
$con = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password) or die ("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database, $con);

mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');
mysql_query('SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=utf8');
mysql_query('SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=utf8');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM events WHERE id='1' ";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Query error: " . mysql_error());
```

Put these codes before you start your SQL statement.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Put it after the `mysql_connect()` and before the `mysql_query($sql)`.

Comment: Use `mysql_set_charset`, not a `SET NAMES` query. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12720360/476.

Comment: thanks but i already put it there it worked, but I'm just asking if there is any other way inter of putting it on every page ??

Comment: i used mysql_set_charset('utf8', $con); it worked just fine, Thanks @deceze & roger

Comment: @BiGHeaD mysql_set_charset('utf8', $con); works for me. Thanks!