# How to encode UTF8 from database with PHP

Tags: php, utf-8

I have simple PHP test API for my database. It queries MySQL DB and returns JSON. Problem is, some values are in Cyrillic and all I get is a question marks. My PHP code is like this:

```
<?php
mysql_connect ( "localhost", "root", "" );
mysql_select_db ( "uni_database" );
$q = mysql_query ( "SELECT * FROM `students`" );
while ( $e = mysql_fetch_assoc ( $q ) )
    $output [] = $e;
print  (json_encode( $output ) );
mysql_close ();

?>
```

Does anyone know how to encode values from DB to UTF8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mysql_connect ( "localhost", "root", "" );
mysql_select_db ( "uni_database" );
mysql_query("set character_set_connection=utf8");
mysql_query("set names utf8");
...
```

Comment: Yes, this helps, but now I am getting something like this: u0441\u0442\u0443\u0434\u0435\u043d\u0442...
So, is there a way to convert this to Cyrillic script?

Comment: Don't `SET NAMES`! See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12720360/476

Comment: @Miller That's exactly what you want! It's JSON encoded characters.

Comment: @Miller Is a json encoded cyrillic.

Comment: @deceze Don't use mysql_!

Comment: @Vlad Sure, but if you do, at least don't `SET NAMES`!

Answer (score 1):

When you create a database make sure it is set to utf8

```
CREATE DATABASE `myDb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Then make the field type as text