# mysql escape string usage in database class

Tags: php, mysql

The project I am working on is using mysql not mysqli.
The database class code where the " where query executes is"

```
if($this->whereCondition != "") {
    $this->sql .= " WHERE $this->whereCondition";
}

if($this->headers != "") {
    $this->sql .= "  $this->headers";
}
```

**$this->whereCondition** contains all the conditions of where statement. Can I use mysql escape string to the whole variable or should I escape individual condition values ??

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12720360/476

Comment: No, you can not apply escaping to complete statements.