# Can this query be bypassed by an injection?

Tags: php, mysql, escaping, sql-injection

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

$checkPassword = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE Username='$username' AND Password='$password';");
```

Can this query be bypassed by an injection and if so is anyone able to craft an injection I can use for security testing?

I have tried doing 'x' or 1=1 but mysql_real_escape_string manages to remove the quotes and treats the whole field as a string.
Thank you all in advance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shortcomings of mysql\_real\_escape\_string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12703420/shortcomings-of-mysql-real-escape-string)

Answer (score 1):

The whole purpose of `mysql_real_escape_string` is to escape any value passed to be safely used in a [MySQL string literal](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-literals.html). And as you use the value escaped by `mysql_real_escape_string` how it’s supposed to be, i. e., only in string literals, you have done everything correctly.

So there is no way to bypass this as long as you have also [set the connection character set properly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5289141/53114) as there is a [case where `mysql_real_escape_string` still may be bypassed due to improper setting of the connection character set when using the character sets GBK or BIG5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12118602/53114).

Answer (score 0):

> Can this query be bypassed by an injection

No.